# Can I create a credentials.yml.enc file outside of Rails and decrypt it using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for how Rails 5.2 encrypts the credentials.yml file. I want to use Chef (but could be anything) to create a credentials.yml.enc file and then set the environment variable so Rails can decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source code for the encrypter. It is using the AES_128_GCM cipher.

[encrypted_file.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb#L22)